# Output array element after generating the array variable name out of other variables in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, echo

I don't do php for quite a while and now i've decided to make a little script but i've ran into a problem i had once before and managed to solve by myself but now i'm not being able to.

Let's say i have 'n' arrays like so...

```
$numbers1=array('32','16','29','41','36');
$numbers2=array('13','50','47','7','39');
$numbers3=array('3','4','29','35','31');
```

and then i want to use a 'for loop' to generate the array names and output certain elements of the arrays and/or the whole array itself like so...

```
for($count1=1;$count1<=3;$count1++)
{
    $num1='numbers'.$count1;
    print_r($$num1); //this outputs what's inside all arrays as expected
    echo $$num1[0];
}
```

The "echo $num1[0]" is the problem and it's on there just to illustrate that i wanted to 'echo' the contents from elements 0 of all arrays obtaining the following output "32133".

I've made a similar question on stackoverflow a long time ago when i was getting started with php but the aswers on that question don't work for this situation and neither the 2 hours i've lost googling together with searching here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `{}`, so PHP knows how to interpret your variable.

```
${$num1}[0]
```

Try that.  That should work the way you want.

`$$num1[0]` is being interpreted as `${$num1[0]}` (so PHP is looking for `$n`).

DEMO: http://codepad.org/yn1JUG5U

Comment: I've tried that as well when i was reviewing stuff from variable variables, unfortunately it isn't working, php doesn't display an error or a result for that. And yes you're right, before php was looking for $n

Comment: it's working now, i've made an error when i modified the lines with your solution, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate like so, but I'd not recommend it. You need to rethink your array setups.

```
<?php
$numbers1=array('32','16','29','41','36');
$numbers2=array('13','50','47','7','39');
$numbers3=array('3','4','29','35','31');

for( $i=1; $i<=3; $i++ )
{
    $array = 'numbers'.$i;
    
    foreach( $$array as $v )
    {
        echo $v .' ';
    }
    
    echo "\n";
}
?>
```

Output:

> 32 16 29 41 36
>
> 13 50 47 7 39
>
> 3 4 29 35 31

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert something like the following:

```
$my_array = $$num1;
echo $my_array[0];
```

**EDIT:** Go for @Rocket's answer - slightly cleaner.